# How to map with a 163 bit number with a 1-bit number?

Tags: vhdl

I have two 163 bit numbers and and I want to map with the multiplier. But for the multiplier, a (162 downto 0) and b is only one bit. So how can I do that? Please help.

```
entity demo_pointadd is
    Port ( x : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (162 downto 0);
           y : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(162 downto 0);
           p : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (162 downto 0);
           q : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (162 downto 0);
          clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
           reset : in  STD_LOGIC);
end demo_pointadd;

-- component declaration
component full_163bitmul
    Port ( a : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (162 downto 0);
           b : in  STD_LOGIC;
           clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
           reset : in  STD_LOGIC;
           c : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (162 downto 0));
end component;
begin
mul_1 :full_163bitmul 
                       port map (a => x,
                                 b => y, --- PROBLEM??
                                 clk => clk,
                                 reset => reset,
                                  c => p);
```

Comment: Do you have the implementation of `full_163bitmul`? If yes, put it in the question. It seems unlikely though, from what you have shown here.

Comment: How does it make any sense to multiply 163-bit number by 1-bit number?

Comment: Johns: Instead of editing this question to be a different question, please post a new one.

Comment: Yes, please ask a new question if you need to. If you revert this again, I will lock this question.

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be no multiplier by itself. when I take a guess on the code of full_163bitmul, the output 'c' will be 'a' (if b='1') or all Zeros (if b='0') or undefined (if b is 'Z' | 'X' | ...).

if you want to build a full multiplier out of it, you have to loop through 'y' vector and bring single bits  to 'b' input and add-and-shift the results.

```
sig_b<=y(i);

mul_1 :full_163bitmul 
port map 
    (a => s_x,
    b => sig_b, 
    clk => clk,
    reset => reset,
    c => temp);

...
```

Comment: Or maybe the `full_163bitmul` has a state machine within and takes both the inputs on port `a`. Otherwise its just a MUX.